# Loop until maximum number

Tags: javascript, arrays, math, filtering

I have several arrays with different lengths that I'm going to loop through. Example:

```
Array1 = ['item', 'item', 'item', 'item']
Array2 = ['item', 'item', 'item', 'item', 'item', 'item', 'item', 'item']
Array3 = ['item', 'item', 'item', 'item', 'item']
Array4 = ['item', 'item', 'item', 'item', 'item', 'item', 'item', 'item', 'item', 'item', 'item', 'item', 'item', 'item', 'item']
```

If the array length is less than for example 10, I want to duplicate the items in the array, but only until the maximum number is met. I don't want to loop more than necessary.

How can I do this? I'm working in javascript now, but I guess it's more of a math question :)

Comment: Have you tried `while(array.length < n) array.push(item)` ?

Comment: Does the array have same item in every index or is that just an example? Is it okay if you get a new array or do you want the same array mutated?

Comment: Can you provide more details of your question? In the answers, I see two completely different interpretations of what you've written, suggesting it could use clarification.

Comment: maybe with the spread operator:   `while(arr.length < 10)
  {
    arr.push(...arr);
  }`

Comment: @toffler and they'd have to `splice(10)` after the loop (if the initial length is not a factor of `10`)

Comment: @adiga depends if the question is just about the amount of loops... if it does not matter that the final size is > 10, then you don't have to splice^^ but the question is unclear about that

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, you have a series of arrays with varying lengths, and you want to loop through an arbitary sequence, say `0 <= n < max`, and use an item from each of the arrays at index `n` but wrapping around to the beginning if the array has too few elements to supply one for index `n`.

If so, you can use the [*remainder operator*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder) to determine the array index to use for any given array: `n % array.length`. For instance:

```
0 % 3 is 0
1 % 3 is 1
2 % 3 is 2
3 % 3 is 0 -- wrapped around!
4 % 3 is 1
5 % 3 is 2
6 % 3 is 0 -- wrapped around again!
```

Here's an example going from 0-9 on arrays that have varying lengths (two of them have fewer than 10 elements, one of them has more):

```js
const array1 = [1, 2, 3];
const array2 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"];
const array3 = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"];

const maximum = 10;

for (let n = 0; n < maximum; ++n) {
    const a = getItem(array1, n); // Or just array1[n % array1.length]
    const b = getItem(array2, n); // Or just array2[n % array2.length]
    const c = getItem(array3, n); // Or just array3[n % array3.length]
    console.log(n, ":", a, b, c);
}

// I've used a function because it would be *really* easy if just
// doing it inline to use `someArray[n % someOtherArray.length`
// and wind up with a bug in the code
function getItem(array, n) {
    const index = n % array.length;
    return array[index];
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```